# Regex on URL string fails when '(' or ')' is present

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have some code that recognises a URL in a string, and converts it to a hyperlink:

```
MyString = Regex.Replace(MyString, 
                         "(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])", 
                         Function(match As Match) String.Format("<a href=""{0}"">{0}</a>", match.ToString()))
```

Unfortunately it is terminating the match early if the string contains either `(` or `)` symbols.  For example...

```
http://my.intranet/CustomerServices/Internal/Staff(Admin)ProcedureChanges.asp
```

...gets replaced with

```
<a href="http://my.intranet/CustomerServices/Internal/Staff">http://my.intranet/CustomerServices/Internal/Staff</a>(Admin)ProcedureChanges.asp
```

Can anyone please amend the RegEx to allow those characters to be included in URL's?  Thank you.

Comment: Try `https?://[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-.,@?^=%&amp;:/~()+#]*[\w\-@?^=%&amp;/~+#])`.

Comment: Seems to work - thank you.  If you can post as an answer I'll accept and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding the `(` and `)` symbols to the third group (and contract the first one to just `https?`):

```
https?://[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-.,@?^=%&amp;:/~()+#]*[\w\-@?^=%&amp;/~+#])
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=https%3F%3A%2F%2F%5B%5Cw%5C-_%5D%2B(%5C.%5B%5Cw%5C-_%5D%2B)%2B(%5B%5Cw%5C-.%2C%40%3F%5E%3D%25%26amp%3B%3A%2F%7E()%2B%23%5D*%5B%5Cw%5C-%40%3F%5E%3D%25%26amp%3B%2F%7E%2B%23%5D)&i=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.intranet%2FCustomerServices%2FInternal%2FStaff(Admin)ProcedureChanges.asp)

Note that you do not need to escape `+` and `.` inside a character class.

[image]

Comment: That's great - thank you very much for the explanation as well.